# flask required attribute cause TemplateSyntaxError: invalid syntax for function call expression

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I tried to combine flask-wtf with required attribute below, but I reviced TemplateSyntaxError: invalid syntax for function call expression

```
{{ form.StudentName(class="Tj-inp1 fl",placeholder='学生姓名:',required)}}
```

Then I run the program, I reviced TemplateSyntaxError: invalid syntax for function call expression. But, if I don't take required attribute. It's ok;

```
StudentName = StringField("学生姓名",validators=[Required(), Length(max=10)])
```

Why required is causing TemplateSyntaxError? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You get a `TemplateSyntaxError` because you have a syntax error in your code. Even in jinja2 (which is what you are probably using) a positional argument can't follow keyword arguments.

You have two keyword arguments: `class` and `placeholder`. After that you are passing `required` as a positional argument. You can't do that.

You probably want something like this:

```
{{ form.StudentName(class="Tj-inp1 fl",placeholder='学生姓名:',required=True)}}
```

or

```
{{ form.StudentName(class="Tj-inp1 fl",placeholder='学生姓名:',required="required")}}
```

Not sure what `flask-wtf` expects here. But the second option is more likely to work.

Comment: @chenlong could you state which of the alternatives was the solution? Or did both of them work?

Comment: @ Wombatz  Both of them can work . My intention is to verify it can't be empty and show the error message. Fortunately,you solved my problem